# In how many ways can two men enter a baseball stadium together and leave by different exits?

Tags: combinatorics

Question:  A baseball stadium has four entrance gates and nine exits. In how many ways may $2$ men enter together, but leave by different exits?

As the stadium has $4$ entrances and they enter together, I knew the fact that all $4$ entrances are possible. But for the exits, I can't process any further.

Comment: Fundamental groups have absolutely nothing to do with this.

Comment: As to your problem, are the men distinguishable?  That is, is it different if $A$ uses exit $1$ and $B$ uses exit $2$ or if $A$ uses $2$ and $B$ uses $1$?

Comment: Ohh sorry. I guess it is fundamental counting principle as the question is beneath that title.

Comment: I have no idea sir :(

Comment: It's your question, we can't decide that for you.  If you have no idea which is intended, then you'll have to answer both versions (that isn't significantly harder).

Comment: Hint:  if they are distinguishable, then $A$ has $9$ choices of exit and $B$ has $8$.

Comment: I thought the answer would be 4 × 9P2.

Comment: Is that reasonable?

Comment: Yes.  That assumes the men are distinguishable.  If they are not, then you need to divide by $2$ to account for the symmetry.

Comment: Thank you sir. It is a lot of help.

Comment: Can i ask for further question sir?

Comment: Question - A tennis club consists of 12 boys and 9 girls. How many mixed teams ( one boy and one girl ) are possible? In how many ways can a mixed doubles match be arranged?

As for the first question , i thought the answer would be 12 × 9 since could be any boy and girl. But for the second question i divide the first answer with 2 since it is about the matches played. Am i right sir?

Comment: You should post a separate question for your tennis club question.  Include everything you wrote in the comment.

Comment: Well, you are right about the $12\times 9$.  For the doubles match, we need to take two teams, so that's $\binom {12\times 9}2$.

Comment: @lulu For the doubles match, we need to select two boys, two girls, and which girl is paired with the younger boy.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Ah, of course my answer is wrong.  Silly error, as my two teams could certainly overlap.